# SoundCloud stream request returning error on Safari iOS

Tags: soundcloud

Getting the following error on Safari iOS (and since I can't get a song to play on Chrome, I'm assuming Chrome is having the same issue).

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'h._setVolume')
line: 38
message: "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'h._setVolume')"
sourceURL: "http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js"
stack: "setVolume@http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js:38:342↵play@http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js:34:153↵↵createAndCallback@http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js:2:5654↵http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js:2:6001↵whenReady@http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js:2:3538↵whenStreamingReady@http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js:2:4474↵stream@http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js:2:5397↵eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"
__proto__: Error
```

I'm getting the above error after running.

```
SC.stream('http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/55499783/stream', function(stream) {
    stream.play();
});
```

Is this a bug in SoundManager?  Am I missing something in the docs?  This exact same codebase works fine in any desktop browser.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue at the moment. Did you manage to get this resolved?

Comment: nah man, it's still been pretty buggy.